# CiviMember Roles Sync is not working in Drupal

Tags: civimember

Drupal version 7.50

CiviCRM version 4.6.10

Hi There,

I activated CiviMember Roles Sync.
[image]

However when I clicked **Configure**, it does not show anything related to the module.

Has anyone experienced this kind of problem?

[image]

Thanks.

Sinarta